Does $\dim C(A)\in\{2,4\}$ for any $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb F$?
Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix over the field $\mathbb F$ and let $C(A)$ denote the subspace of all $2\times 2$ matrices that commute with $A$, that is
$$
C(A)=\{X\in M_2(\mathbb F):AX=XA\}
$$
Does it always hold that $\dim C(A)\in\{2,4\}$?
My attempt: If $A=aI_2$ for some $a\in\mathbb F$, then $\dim C(A)=4$. Otherwise, $I,A\in C(A)$ and since $I,A$ are linearly independent, it follows that $2\leq \dim C(A)$. Can it happen that $\dim C(A)=3$?

You have show that the dimension is either $\le 2$, or $4$. Where is your doubt? See also this post.

Thanks @Dietrich but why it is $\leq 2$?

But that implies that the dimension is $\geq 2$, doesn't it?

Solving the system of equations in the four variables of $X$ determines then already $2$ variables, because $A$ and $I$ are linearly independent. So there are at most two free variables left for $X$. So $\le 2$ and not $\ge 2$ (sorry, my comment was misleading).

Consider the linear map $\mathrm{ad}_A: M_2(\mathbb F)\to M_2(\mathbb F)$ given by $\mathrm{ad}_A(X)=AX-XA$. Observe that $C(A)=\ker \mathrm{ad}_A$.
Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with every entry $0$ except $(i,j)$. $\{E_{11}, E_{21}, E_{12}, E_{22}\}$ is the standard ordered basis of $M_2(\mathbb F)$.
Take $A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$.
Now,
$\mathrm{ad}_A(E_{11})= AE_{11}-E_{11}A = \pmatrix{0&-b\\c&0}$.
$\mathrm{ad}_A(E_{21})= AE_{21}-E_{21}A = \pmatrix{b&0\\d-a&-b}$.
$\mathrm{ad}_A(E_{12})= AE_{12}-E_{12}A = \pmatrix{-c&a-d\\0&c}$.
$\mathrm{ad}_A(E_{22})= AE_{22}-E_{22}A = \pmatrix{0&b\\-c&0}$.
The matrix of $\mathrm{ad}_A$ is given below:
$$\pmatrix{0&b&-c&0\\c&d-a&0&-c\\-b&0&a-d&b\\0&-b&c&0}$$
It is easy to show that rank of this matrix cannot be $1$ and hence $\dim\ker\mathrm{ad}_A=\dim C(A)$ can't be equal to $3$.
Performing row and column operations...
Update $R_3$ with $R_3+R_1$.
$$\pmatrix{0&b&-c&0\\c&d-a&0&-c\\-b&0&a-d&b\\0&0&0&0}$$
Update $C_1$ with $C_1+C_3$.
$$\pmatrix{0&b&-c&0\\0&d-a&0&-c\\0&0&a-d&b\\0&0&0&0}$$
[We can mix row and column operations since we are only interested in the rank and neither the column space nor the nullspace.]
Work with the two cases: $a\neq d$ and $a=d$.
In case 1, the submatrix $\pmatrix{a-d&0\\0&d-a}$ is of rank two.
In case 2, the submatrix $\pmatrix{b&-c&0\\0&0&-c\\0&0&b}$ has rank two if at least one of $b$ or $c$ is non-zero. If both $b,c=0$ then the original matrix itself is the zero matrix.

Alternatively, once we have the matrix representation of $\operatorname{ad}_A$ in hand, exchanging the second and third columns (or second and third rows) preserves the rank and yields an alternating matrix (a skew-symmetric matrix with zero diagonal entries). But every alternating matrix has even rank (see, e.g., Lang's Algebra, Chapter XV, Theorem 8.1), so $\dim C(A) = \operatorname{null} \operatorname{ad}_A$ is even.

@TravisWillse Good observation! I did know this fact about alternating matrices... But didn't see that it would be alternating matrix with second and third row exchanged... There could some other basis that $E_{ij}$'s which makes this obvious?

I don't see a natural choice that would achieve that if we use the same bases for the domain and codomain copies of $M_2(\Bbb F)$, but since we only care about the rank of the transformation, we might as well switch the second and third elements of one basis or the other, which gives the discussed alternating matrix.
